# Adding more entries replaces everything instead of adding

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core

Good day I am new in mongodb, I can successfully perform a CRUD, but now I want to dig deep into mongoDB. I have this JSON and I want it to update my database once it has a data, and create a new one if it doesn't exist, but what happens is it always replace my value for the "LeaderboardDetails".

Here is the MongoDB JSON:

```
{
    "id" : "secretsomething",
    "UserID" : "zgahsjd",
    "category" : "testing",
    "Score" : 2000,
    "Badges" : 0,
    "LeaderboardDetails": {
        "id": "123123123213",
        "ScoreForDay": 10000,
        "BadgesForDay": 0
    } 
}
```

When I submit to update the "LeaderboardDetails" it should add a new entry if it doesn't exist, otherwise update the current one , but instead it replaces it.

Here is my code for PUT:

```
public void Update(string id, SomeModel newScore)
{
    _record.ReplaceOne(scores => scores.id == id, newScore);
}
```

Here is the SomeModel Code:

```
    [Required]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "UserID")]
    public string UserID { get; set; }

    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "category")]
    public string category { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Score { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Badges { get; set; }

    public class LeaderboardIDToSend
    {
        public string id;

        public string ScoreForDay;

        public string BadgesForDay;

        public LeaderboardIDToSend(string _id, string _score, string _badges)
        {
            id = _id;
            ScoreForDay = _score;
            BadgesForDay = _badges;
        }
    }
    [Required]
    public LeaderboardIDToSend LeaderboardDetails;
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your json, `leaderBoardDetails` is an object, but it should be a list of objects, that is the first modification you should do, second, in order for you to add an item to set, you should use `Builders<T>.Update.AddToSet(c => c.leaderBoardDetails, leaderboardDto)`, now regarding your concern, you want to upsert the object, as far as I know, and looking at [Array Update Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update-array/), there is no such operator, so you will have to do this manually, you need to load all your existing leader, then check if this id exist, if so, you need to update its values, and then Update the whole list (leaderBoardDetails), if it doesn't exist, you can simple use [AddToSet](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.5/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_Builders_Update_AddToSet.htm) operator